# can't be helped by

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What's the meaning of "helped" in the following passage?

> A modifying word usually specifies the czar's area of responsibility: drug is the commonest, followed by terms such as health, border, security, and counterterrorism. Many people are uncomfortable with the power and influence of these modern czars, a feeling that can't be **helped** by the choice of a name traditionally associated with authoritarian rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Help" in this case means "prevent" or "avoid". [Merriam-Webster's definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/helped) is:

> to refrain from : AVOID

The author means: because the name is traditionally associated with authoritarian rule, no one can prevent (or avoid) the feeling of being uncomfortable with their power and influence.

Comment: Are "helped" and "avoided" interchangeable in the OP sentence?

Comment: I find "Many people are uncomfortable with the power and influence of these modern czars, a feeling that can't be **avoided because** the choice of the name **is** traditionally associated with authoritarian rule" reasonable. But NOT "Many people are uncomfortable with the power and influence of these modern czars, a feeling that can't be **avoided by the choice of a name traditionally associated with authoritarian rule.**

Comment: Yes, "avoided" can be substitued for "helped" in the original sentence. I agree that "by" is not a very good preposition to use there; something like "due to" or "as a result of" might work better. Your solution (using the subordinating conjunction "because") works well, too.